# Qual a diferença entre descompilar código de linguagem de baixo nível e alto nível?

Tags: descompilação

O que torna tão complexo descompilar códigos de baixo nível, como por exemplo rom de jogos, sendo que exitem bons descompiladores para linguagens como Java e C++?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: *"rom de jogos"* uma rom em geral nem é código compilado, pode ser mapas de fases, cenários, audio, etc, não necessariamente um programa.. isso não é um bom exemplo.... quanto mais baixo nível, menos se tem a descompilar, pq a princípio já foi feito o mais próximo da linguagem de máquina, ou seja, com o mínimo de compilação no sentido de traduzir o código de alto nível

Comment: Entendi. Muito grato @RicardoPontual!
Por isso que as pessoas editam o código de rom em um editor hexadecimal ao invés de reprogramarem ela, certo?